# Name alias in mapping query parameters to object in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, query-string

I have a class

```
class Request {
    
    private String ftr;
    // more properties
}
```

And a method in controller class

```
@GetMapping
public String list(@Valid Request request) {
    //...
}
```

When I send a request to the method the url is `https://example.com?ftr=sms`

Is it possible to have an alias to a query parameter like in the class

```
class Request {
    
    @QueryParameter(name="ftr")
    private String filter;
    // ...
}
```

And to map same request url to this class?

Answer (score 0):

You can just annotate your request parameter by `@RequestParam(name = "ftr")` like below:

```
@GetMapping
public String list(@RequestParam(name = "ftr") @Valid String filter, ...) {
    //...
}
```

but you can't do it to pass an Object like you did, so you need to pass each field as a parameter, or you can use a map to encapsulate all your parameters like this:

```
@GetMapping
public String list(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
    //...
}
```

and this is a list of all request annotations that you can use with your methods:

- RequestParam  : used for get params
- PathVariable  : used for path params
- RequestHeader : used for headers params
- RequestBody   : used for post/put/patch/... body

Comment: I doesn't work. Also in the `Request` class I can have more properties.

Comment: you are right sorry, so please check https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#name--